# How to install NumPy on Windows 64?

Tags: python, windows-7, numpy, windows-7-x64

NumPy installer can't find python path in the registry.

> ---
>
> ### Cannot install
>
> ### Python version 2.5 required, which was not found in the registry.
>
> ### OK

I have to modify the registry?
I already modified %PATH% to point to the Python25 installation directory.

Comment: What version of NumPy are you trying to install and what installer package?

Comment: @Vecdid numpy-1.4.0-sse3

Comment: @Vecdid numpy-1.4.0-win32-superpack-python2.5

Comment: This problem persists with the NumPy Windows Superpack for Python 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy is not supported on python 2.5 for Windows 64 bits, you need at least python 2.6, and even in that case, you need to build it by yourself, or use something like EPD or the installer given in link given by thor.

NumPy cannot be used in Google App Engine, so I am not sure to understand the argument there.

Answer (score 5):

can I check what installer you're using for this?  I don't think there is an official 64bit Numpy binary, but there is an unofficial one you can try [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
Of course, if you've already tried this installer then let me know.

Comment: I haven't tried until your answer, but I can't make it work neither

Answer (score 2):

Something is strange with the official superpack...

http://scipy.org/Download

> Windows 64 bit unofficial releases Christoph Gohlke has put together
>   an impressive collection of Windows binary installers of recent
>   versions of scientific packages for Python, including amd64 versions
>   of Numpy and Scipy compiled against Intel's MKL, and SciKits:
>   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs

**The unofficial release solved this installation problem.**