# Can't find correct numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Level:noob

I took a MIT OCW course that requires an unofficial numpy for python 2.6.x 64 bit for windows platform. I googled for 2 hrs! But can't find or just don't recognize it!
Can anyone sort it out?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you mean unofficial? You should ask the course handlers for 
 the `numpy` version used.

Comment: Sounds like you were told about [Gohlke's unofficial Windows Python binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) - they haven't had a build of Numpy for Python 2.6 x64 in a while though. Also, you can just use Python 2.7. Python 2.6 has been end-of-lifed for a few years.

Comment: Here's what they stated(they gave a link too but it isn't there):
Unofficial numpy for Python 2.6.x (64-bit) (select numpy-unoptimized-1.6.1.win-amd64-py2.6.exe; make sure you get the py2.6 part correct.) 64-bit numpy is not officially supported, however, Unofficial binaries exist at the above website courtesy of Christoph Gohlke (UC Irvine).

Comment: You don't have to follow those instructions to the letter for setting up your Python environment. Go download a [64-bit build of Python 2.7 for Windows](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) and [the Numpy for `amd_64` build from Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). All the Python and `numpy` code the OCW course uses will probably run as-is.

Comment: @birryree  Yes, it&#39;s if Gohlke&#39;s. But they still say for Python 2.6 .Anyway Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no unofficial 2.6 + 64-bit NumPy because NumPy [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2182498/7954504) on this combination.

The closest thing is a 2.7 64-bit binary:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

This is the site that you reference in your question and comments, and the lowest Python version there is 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the same courses and you can't really have the full grasp of the content without installing all the software used and go through the labs. I had the same problem with numPy not working on 64bit computer and the link provided in the course was no longer providing the desired package...

Solution:

Just install the 32bit version of all the software (link provided below) which works even on a 64bits computer.

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/software-and-tools/installing-the-6.01-software-on-windows-7-xp-32-bit/

I hope that this will help anyone struggling with the same issue

[MIT soar and cMax sofware working on 64bits windows 10 computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qpfc.jpg)